# Removing difficult :before content

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove the word "Category" from before my Endorsements text but the CSS I'm using isn't working out. Please see below.

**The HTML Element**
HTML

```
    <h1 class="page-title">
    ::before
    "Category:"
    <span>Endorsements</span>
    ::after
    </h1>
```

CSS

**Try 1**
CSS

```
    .page-title::before{
        content: none;
        }
```

**Try 2**
CSS

```
    h1.page-title::before{
        content: none;
        }
```

Try 3
CSS

```
    .page-title::before{
        display: none;
        }
```

**Try 4**
CSS

```
    h1.page-title::before{
        display: none;
        }
```

Comment: The selector specificity is probably not enough high. If `!important` helps, this is certainly due to specificity.

Comment: Have you tried adding `content: "";`, or `content: "" !important;`?

Comment: Is the word coming from the CSS, somewhere? If it is then just remove that word from the relevant `content` property. If it's in the HTML then CSS won't, and can't, remove it.